# automatic TrueLayer login for test purposes

Tags: node.js, authentication, automation

Does anyone knows how to login automatically in TrueLayer's API service (for example as a mock user) for testing purposes. In my case I'm using Node.js (ES6) with Sails.js.  If that is possible of course.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Reading their documentation https://docs.truelayer.com/#authentication is a good start. Also, you should include what you have tried so others may be able to point out what may help you solve the problem.

Comment: I'm creating an app which has to use TrueLayer's API to download information on user's transactions. This is just a demo app, but still has to be tested. So I am thinking how to test the app with empty db, when to fill it up I need a user to pass through the login/redirect process. I was thinking to have a hardcoded user, or just to hardcode/save somehow mock user's tokens so I can test the helpers with it.

https://github.com/ivanski1024/emma-sails/blob/master/api/controllers/UserController.js

Answer (score 0):

You can refer truelayer's documentation. Once you log in there you can see respective details under Data/Payment API. They provide mock bank with mock user for testing purpose.